# getting error "TypeError: Router.use() requires a middleware function but got a undefined" while trying to import a router from other file

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, backend

I am trying to write a router for all the user paths and exported it to use in index.js. When i try to use the userRouter in the index.js i am getting the error

```js
C:\Users\yugi\OneDrive\Documents\codes\NodeJs\API_nodejs\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:469
      throw new TypeError('Router.use() requires a middleware function but got a ' + gettype(fn))
      ^

TypeError: Router.use() requires a middleware function but got a undefined
    at Function.use (C:\Users\yugi\OneDrive\Documents\codes\NodeJs\API_nodejs\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:469:13)
    at Function.<anonymous> (C:\Users\yugi\OneDrive\Documents\codes\NodeJs\API_nodejs\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:227:21)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Function.use (C:\Users\yugi\OneDrive\Documents\codes\NodeJs\API_nodejs\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:224:7)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\yugi\OneDrive\Documents\codes\NodeJs\API_nodejs\index.js:22:5)
```

but when i export it in this format

```js
module.exports = {
userRouter:router
}
```

everything works file without any problem.

there is one other router file for api paths in routes, I removed that file to see if it is the problem but the error still persisted.

This is the user router i wrote

```js
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const { getAllUsers, createNewUser, getUserById, updateUserData, deleteUser } = require('../controllers/userController')

router.use(express.json())
router.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }))

router.route('/')
    .get(getAllUsers)
    .post(createNewUser)

router.route('/:id')
    .get(getUserById)
    .patch(updateUserData)
    .delete(deleteUser)


module.exports = router
```

index.js file

```js
//imported files

require('dotenv').config()
const express = require('express');
const { getConnection } = require('./connection')
const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080
const { userRouter } = require('./routes/userRoutes')

//connection

try {
    getConnection
    console.log('connected to db');
}
catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
}

//middleware
// console.log(apiRouter)
app.use("/users", userRouter);

//listening 

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`server started on http://localhost:${PORT}`)
})
```

Comment: check the value of `userRouter` I guess

Comment: like print it on to console, if yes then i did that and result was undefined

Comment: well, then, you probably need `const userRouter = require('./routes/userRoutes')` instead - since the `router` in `module.exports = router` doesn't have a property `userRouter` ... or what you did below `but when i export it in this format` should've worked too

Comment: @Jaromanda X
thank for the reply i checked my code once again after your reply the problem was i am exporting the router as router like this `module.exports = { router }` and when i am trying to use it i am using userRouter to import the file `const { userRouter } = require('./routes/userRoutes')` which is not in that file so i am getting the error

Comment: if you export `{ router }` then you'll need to either `const { router } = require(...)` or `const { router: userRouter } = require(...)` if you want the variable to be called `userRouter` - in future, you should post the code you have an issue with ... since the code you posted you use `module.exports = router`

Comment: if, however, you `module.exports = {userRouter:router}` ... then `const {userRouter} = require(...)` should work .... obviously `...` is just a stand in for the actual path that I don't want to type out every time :p

Comment: thank you for explaining, I am beginner and it was a silly mistake. inconsistencies in export and import was the problem

Answer (score 0):

The problem was inconsistence in import and export.

if we see the export in router file, it was exported as router object, but in index file it is accessed as a object with router as it's property

export in router file

```js
module.exports = router
```

import in index file

```js
const { userRouter } = require('./routes/userRoutes')
```

which causes an inconsistence between import and export.

the correct way was to import it as a solo object like this

```js
module.exports = router //export in router file
const userRouter =  require('./routes/userRoutes') //import in index file
```

or should have exported it as a object with property of router like this

```js
module.exports = {router} //export in router file
const {router} =  require('./routes/userRoutes') //import in index file
```